# Gridview not populating after adding DataKeyNames

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that populates from a data table when a button is clicked.

The code goes like this:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { 
                        new DataColumn("One", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Two", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Three",typeof(string)) });

    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["---"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM ---", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(reader["One"].ToString(), reader["Two"].ToString(), reader["Three"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();
```

Now whenever i try to add a DataKeyName to the gridview, it would not be populated.

I tried setting it manually and using

```
    GridView2.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"Key"};
```

Comment: where did you called this GridView2.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"Key"}; ?? after gridbind ?? or before ??

Comment: is gridview dynamically created in code behind ??\

Comment: did you check whether datatable is empty ??

Comment: Gridview is created in aspx. Everything works fine until I try to input datakey. Is the way im setting the data key wrong?

Comment: Couple of code suggestions, cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); is of no use in the above code and conn.Close(); should be outside of using clause of SQLCommand.Better to use using clause for the SQLConnection as well.Coming to setting the DataKeyName, "Key" should be the name of one or more of the columns you have added GridView2.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"One","Two"};

Comment: @inquisitive_mind, turns out my DataKeyNames was not in the columns. Thanks, you might wanna write it down as an answer